# Call method of another contract from one contract in upgradable smartcontract

Tags: inheritance, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

I have two contracts **Vase** and **Box**

```
contract Vase {
    uint256 public vase1;
    event VaseValueChanged(uint256 newValue);

    function createVase(uint256 newValue) public {
        vase1 = newValue;
        emit VaseValueChanged(newValue);
    }

    // Reads the last stored value
    function retrieveVase() external view returns (uint256) {
        return vase1;
    }
}
```

```
contract Box {
    uint256 private value;



    // Stores a new value in the contract
    function store(uint256 newValue, uint256 breadth) public {
        value = newValue;
    }


}
```

Both are upgradable smartcontracts and I am using the openzeppelin library and using its CLI for upgrading these  contracts.

How can I call **retrieveVase()** method of **Vase** contract from **Box** contract. I don't want to inherit Vase in Box contract.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is related to upgradable contracts? Or is this simply a question about "how can I reference another contract in my contract"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the 2 following options:

1. Via interface contract:

**ContractA.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract A {
    uint256 public testVariable = 5;
    
    function getTestVariable() public view returns(uint256) {
        return testVariable;
    }
}
```

**ContractB.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract B {
    A a_contract_instance;
    constructor(address _a_contract_address) public {
        a_contract_instance = A(_a_contract_address);
    }
    
    function callToContractA() public view returns(uint256) {
        return a_contract_instance.getTestVariable();
    }
}

interface A {
    function getTestVariable() external view returns(uint256);
}
```

2. Via `.call()` function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ExistingContract  {
    uint256 test_val;
    address test_addr;
    
    function getA() public view returns (uint256, address) {
        return (test_val, test_addr);
    }
    
    function setA(uint256 _val) public {
        test_val = _val;
        test_addr = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract Caller {
    function externalCallGetA(address _addr) public returns(uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(_addr).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("getA()"));
        require(success);
        
        return abi.decode(result, (uint256));
    }
    
    function externalCallSetA(address _addr, uint256 _var) public{
        (bool success,) = address(_addr).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setA(uint256)", _var));
        require(success);
    }
}
```